# MYSQL query if syntax

Tags: mysql

I have a question regarding an SQL syntax.

I have a mysql table like this `(id, name, subid, preview)` where preview is set to `0` as default. So now I want to make a select to query only lines where `preview` is different from zero.

Can I do this in a single query .. or I need to query all and then make (`if else`) decisions?

like `SELECT * FROM table_name;` - and iterate through ... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```
select *
from mytable
where preview != 0
```

`!=` means "not equal to". Some databases also use `<>` for the same meaning.

If preview is nullable, do you also want to return rows where preview is null? If so, you may want to try:

```
select *
from mytable
where preview != 0 or preview is null
```

Answer (score 1):

Put condition in `WHERE`

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
WHERE  preview !=0
```

Answer (score 1):

Also worth to point out is that while `*` will do fine, you should always try to specify which columns you need in your query, so it be more clear what the query actually retrieves, so

```
SELECT id, name, subid, preview from table_name WHERE preview != 0
```

is more clear than `SELECT *`, but anyway all the other answers are right too.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE preview != 0;
```

?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use query like this: select * from table_name where preview <> 0